# Prevent embedded video appearing above image overlay

Tags: 6, javascript, nodes

http://www.fareham.ac.uk/news/2011/10/17/skins-star-inspires-students

The above page includes an image gallery, powered by the [Brilliant Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/brilliant_gallery) module.

The problem: when a thumbnail from the Gallery is clicked, the embedded YouTube video beneath the Gallery section appears above the image overlay (powered by the [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module).

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of [wmode](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html)

Comment: I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue